# Can identities running on Indy be referenced in Fabric blockchain?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

As it stands today, Can identities running on Indy be referenced in Fabric blockchain (like in a smart contract)?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no native integration between Fabric and Indy and you can't use Indy DIDs to sign Fabric transactions.  Fabric v1.1 and later does have a somewhat [pluggable](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.1/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L345-L375) authentication mechanism as well as a pluggable decorator (ability to add additional data to the payload passed into chaincode) where you *might* be able to leverage an Indy identity.